# StoreContext.GetAppLicenseAsync().AddOnLicenses sometimes returns an empty list when the user has a license

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store, xbox

I have an XBOX only app in the Microsoft Store that has been up for a while. The app has an add-on.

I use a very simple code to get the list of licenses in order to check if the user has add-on.
See below.

```cs
StoreAppLicense appLicense = await StoreContext.GetAppLicenseAsync();

var licenses = appLicense.AddOnLicenses.Select(item=> item.Value).ToList();

//Here I just save this in my log to see what is in the list
LogInfo("licenses: " + string.Join(',', licenses.Select(l => l.SkuStoreId).ToArray()));
```

Ok, so most of the time this code works fine. But there can be instances where the StoreAppLicense returns an **empty list**, even when  **the user HAS the license**.

This has been a problem that has happened sometimes since I published the add-on, but was always fixed by reinstalling the app. Lately, even after a reinstall; the issue reappears.

What is worst, this even happened to me two days ago. I reinstalled the app and it worked fine; but after restarting the app it happened again. Then after some hours when I came back home it "solved itself".

I also have the suspicion that sometimes the StoreContext.GetAppLicenseAsync() method never returns and that causes the app to "hang".

Needless to say, customers get upset at me and give me bad reviews for something that is beyond my control.

What should I do in this situation? Can you even trust the StoreContext library?
Has someone seen this happening before?

Comment: The code is correct. Not sure if this is related to the store server. Please open a free support ticket here: **[Contact Us](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support)**. Go to Contact us Tab, find **Non-Technical Support - Dashboard**  and choose **CHAT NOW** or **SUBMIT AN INCIDENT**. Trying to check this behavior with the team to see if this is an issue with the server.

Comment: I may be wrong. But some changes have occurred in the support page. The chat is gone and opening a case seems to always cost $200

Comment: No, the ticket should be free if you are rasing a ticket for `Non-Technical Support - Dashboard`. Try to submit an incident instead.